# How to configure the joints added for the vacuum_gripper plugin?

Tags: gazebo, ros-noetic, gripper

I am following this https://answers.ros.org/question/243080/need-help-to-trigger-the-vacuum-gripper/ to implement a vacuum gripper for my custom robot. I found out that I need to add other links to my robot at the end effector. These links must be attached to the end effector via 'revolute' joints, something like this:

```
    <link name="vacuum_gripper1">
      <gravity>0</gravity>
      <visual>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <box size="0.01 0.01 0.01"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="transparent">
          <color rgba="0 0 0 0"/>
        </material>
      </visual>
      <inertial>
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.000000 0.000000 0.000000"/>
        <mass value="0.0001"/>
        <inertia ixx="1e-08" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-08" iyz="0" izz="1e-08"/>
      </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="gripper_joint1" type="revolute">
      <parent link="link_vac" />
      <child link="vacuum_gripper1" />
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.135 0.09 -0.0355" />
      <axis xyz="1 0 0" />
      <limit effort="50" velocity="50" lower="0" upper="0" />
      <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="10"/>
    </joint> 

  <gazebo>
      <plugin name="gazebo_ros_vacuum_gripper1" filename="libgazebo_ros_vacuum_gripper.so">
        <robotNamespace>/v1</robotNamespace>
        <bodyName>vacuum_gripper1</bodyName>
        <topicName>grasping1</topicName>
    <maxForce>50</maxForce>
        <maxDistance>0.05</maxDistance>
        <minDistance>0.001</minDistance>
      </plugin>
  </gazebo>
```

My question is, do I have to add the transmissions and the controllers for these joints? Maybe I should mention that whether I add them or not, the gripper does not work. But when I don't add them, I have this warning:

```
The complete state of the robot is not yet known.  Missing gripper_joint1,...
```